# Show intermediate answer when querying DNS

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-route53, dig

My company has multiple layers of DNS before arriving at a specific node, for example:

```
domain1.company.com                     CNAME domain2.company.com
domain2.company.com                     CNAME domain3.hosted_zone_id.easn.company.com
domain3.hosted_zone_id.easn.company.com A     10.1.2.3
```

The terminating node is an AWS EC2 instance. I need to find all the layers associated with the first domain name(`domain1.company.com`).

If I use:

```
dig domain1.company.com
```

I only get back the final IP address. A college's computer is showing the full path but I can't find the the option in `dig` to toggle that. Both of us are running dig 9.10.6, but he was on macOS and I'm on Ubuntu.

Is there an option in dig to display the intermediate domain names?

Comment: `dig +trace` or `+additional`  maybe ?

Comment: Play around a bit with digwebinterface.com, that's a website where you have all the dig options

Comment: I am curious: Why is your company using multiple CNAMES. That slows down DNS requests, requires more maintenance and configuration and leaks potentially sensitive information (hostnames).